# Рівень якості «Словника української мови в 11 томах 1970–1980 років»(СУМ-11) на 2019 рік згідно норм сучасної української мови

Tags: resource-request, словники, документація

[«Словник української мови в 11 томах 1970–1980 років»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) - досить відомий словник в укрнеті, сайти з оцифрованими версіями якого - `ukrlit.org,  inmo.org.ua, sum.in.ua` - користуються популярністю.
Я теж ним іноді користуюся, проте деякі слова, які я знаходив в цьому словнику, м'яко кажучи, викликають певні сумніви. Наприклад: в [онлайн коректорі](http://onlinecorrector.com.ua) стверджується, що вживання дієприкметників активного стану з -уч-, -юч- не рекомендовано нормами сучасної української мови, проте в даному словнику таких слів досить багато. І багато іншого.

Наскільки цей словник відповідає стандартам та нормам сучасної мови? Варто ним користуватися чи імовірність зіткнутися із застарілим/неіснуючим словом занадто велика? Які є оцифровані альтернативи?

Comment: Цей допис виглядає як запрошення до висловлення субʼєктивних думок. Щоб зробити запитання більш обʼєктивним, бажано вказати критерії «надійності» джерела. На запитання, сформульоване так, як воно є зараз, відповідь може бути лише одна: багато користувачів послуговуються саме цим словником. Більше сказати, на мою думку, нічого не можна.

Comment: Всі критерії по яким ви судите, чи словник є об'єктивним. Я не знаю жодного тому не написав. Крім того, хіба це не платформа для висловлення суб'єктивних відповідей?

Comment: Про всяк випадок: sum.in.ua — це оцифрована версія [«Словника української мови» в 11 томах 1970–1980 років](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/Словник_української_мови_в_11_томах), той самий словник є в оцифрованому вигляді й на інших сайтах, наприклад, [на ukrlit.org](http://ukrlit.org/slovnyk/slovnyk_ukrainskoi_movy_v_11_tomakh), [на inmo.org.ua](http://www.inmo.org.ua/sum.html) — тож, мабуть, доречніше ставити питання, чи доречно довіряти словнику, а не чи доречно довіряти одному із сайтів, що його показує.

Comment: @Sasha Я не знав, що є більше, ніж один сайт. Зараз виправлю. Дякую.

Comment: Я вважаю, що відсутність полеміки і високі вимоги як до запитань, так і до відповідей є перешкодою до массовості. Хоча дискусійність закладено в саму основу платформи, наприклад тою ж таки системою рейтингового оцінювання запитань і відповідей.

Comment: Також хочу додати до запитання сумніви щодо використання закінчення -ся в кінці слів. Бо коли читаєш старі тексти 1900-х років, то стає зрозумілим значення -ся. 
Практично будь-яке речення зі словом із закінченням -ся можна перефразувати таким чином, щоб позбавити речення подібного слова. 
А це цікаво, адже я звернув увагу, що якщо спробувати ввести за правило уникання слів із закінченням -ся, то речення стають зрозуміліші і точніші.

Comment: @stegetsj Дякую. Частково, тут іде і відповідь на моє питання. Я взагалі не знав про СУМ 20. Я так розумію, що краще користуватися саме ним замість СУМ 11, чи не так? Не знаєте часом чи є сайти із СУМ 20? Я думаю, це було б вичерпною відповіддю на моє загальне питання.

Comment: @stegetsj Я думаю відповідь на питання-родич та ваш коментар із лінком на сайт із СУМ 20 разом дають відповідь на моє питання, можливо не вичерпну, але відповідь. Дякую всім, хто відписував.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[«Словник української мови в 11 томах 1970–1980 років»](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D0%B2_11_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85) щодо сучасної мови застарів, бо:

- хоч i не суттєво, але вже змінювали правописи, пак [2019 року](//mon.gov.ua/storage/app/media/zagalna%20serednya/%202019.pdf). З вицифрованих із словників сайтів, що були перелічені, лише [sum.in.ua](http://sum.in.ua/) вказує на застарілість — приклад [*жюрі*](http://sum.in.ua/s/zhjuri), але не завжди.
- вже вицифровують новіший — [Словник української мови у 20 томах (СУМ-20)](//uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA_%D1%83%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%97%D0%BD%D1%81%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%97_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B8_%D1%83_20_%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%85), з котрого видрукнули 13 книг — до слова *покірний*. Ось [субʼєктивне порівняння двох словників](/q/4684/585) та [сайт](//services.ulif.org.ua/expl) ([алтернатівний](//sum20ua.com/)) із вицифрованою версією вищеназваного словника.

Comment: я пропоную писати пояснення до незвичних термінів у дужках, щоб людина не мала їх шукати.

Comment: посилання на [сайт](https://services.ulif.org.ua/expl) наразі не працює

Comment: @whatserface dodav alternativnu lanku.

Answer (score 4):

**СУМ-11**

Як же його сприйняли критики? Відповідь ми можемо отримати з роботи Василя Німчука "[ПРО СУЧАСНУ УКРАЇНСЬКУ ТЛУМАЧНУ ЛЕКСИКОГРАФІЮ](https://r2u.org.ua/node/270)", де пише:

> Об́́’єктом зазіхань став, зокрема, академічний одинадцятитомний
>   «Словник української мови» (1970–1980 pp.), провідним редакторам і
>   авторам якого – акад. В. М. Русанівському та І. К. Білодідові, д.ф.н.
>   Л. Г. Скрипник, А. А. Бурячкові, В. О. Винникові, Г. М. Гнатюк, С І.
>   Головащукові, к.ф.н. Л. С. Паламарчукові, Л. О. Родніній, Л. А. Ющук,
>   Т. К. Чарторизькій – 1983 р. присвоєно звання лауреатів Державної
>   премії СРСР. Ця багаторічна праця справедливо визнана вершиною
>   української лексикографії. Вона такою фактично є і нині.

Що ж пише про цей словник [Олександр Пономарів](https://detector.media/community/article/66981/2011-11-07-oleksandr-ponomariv-na-nashomu-tb-chas-vvoditi-movnii-rezhim/):

> Є академічний одинадцятитомний Словник української мови (1971-1980).
>   Цей словник хоч і не без вад, але робили його фахівці.
>
> Коли почала втілюватися в життя радянська теорія зближення мов, за
>   якою нібито всі мови повинні були злитися в одну, зі словників
>   заходилися викидати слова суто українські, які не схожі на російські.
>   І, щоб зберегти ці слова, мовознавці залишали їх із примітками
>   «застаріле», «обласне», «діалектне», «рідковживане», аби тільки вони
>   були в словнику.

Потрбіно розуміти, що коли укладали СУМ-11, то для наша держава переживала не найкращі часи. Гадаю, що це основний мінус цього словника. Підтвердження цих слів можна знайти в роботі Святослава Карнавського "[Пошук українського слова](http://maysterni.com/p6.htm)":

> Розмір статті не дозволяє дати повну картину кастрування нашої мови,
>   здій- сненої СУМом.  Заразом Словник практикує такий маневр: варто
>   письменникові ока- зійно /наприклад, у листуванні/ вжити російське
>   слово, як воно моментально фік- сується як норма.  Наприклад:
>                                 баловство 
>                                 нарядний
>                                 обмовитися 
>                                 повітряний поцілунок.
>        Спотворено у Словнику і наголосову систему української мови.  Наприклад, слова 
>                            переспів, старіти, перебіг, перебіжка,  у Словнику мають або подвійний наголос, або спільний з російським. 
>   Подвійний наголос служить переходом до російського:
>                            переспів, старіти, перебіг.
>        Подвійний наголос у слові перебіг дозволяє у слові перебіжка поставити ро- сійський наголос уже без подвійної комбінації:
>   перебіжка.
>        Деякі тлумачення СУМу просто неграмотні.  Наприклад:
>        Оливо витлумачено як олово, і дано приклади з класиків, котрі, як ми зна- ємо вживали це слово в українському неспотвореному значенні,
>   що відповідало су- часному накинутому слову свинець.  СУМ наводить
>   цитату з Л. Українки:
>                       ”...топлять оливо, ллють кулі”.
>        А кулі ж ллють не з олова (Stanum), а із свинцю (Plumbum).  Отже, оливо в  мові Л. Українки, як і в мові українців, значило не олово, а
>   свинець.
>        Аналогічно СУМ слово олив’яний тлумючить як олов’яний. Чи треба пояснювати, що словникове тлумачення - абсурд?
>        Словник збиватиме з пантелику не лише сучасників, але й прийдешні поколін- ня.  Отже, шкоду заподіяно на багато років наперед.

Крім того, не забувайте, що в нас вже є **СУМ-20** (хоч, він ще не закінчений).

Про цей словник я чув багато хорошого і багато поганого. Сам його використовую рідше ніж СУМ-11 через те, що він ще не закінчений. Хочу процитувати деякі фрагменти із статті "[Перший том золотого дванадцятикнижжя: радісно... і гірко](https://www.ulif.org.ua/page/piershii-tom-zolotogo-dvadtsiatiknizhzhia-radisno-i-girko)":

> У 20-томовикові перші 18 томів, містять загальну лексику, а
>   географічні назви (близько 70 тисяч назв) подано в останніх двох
>   томах. У надзвичайно ґрунтовній передмові до словника (т.1) зазначено,
>   що "у його авторів виробився новий погляд на тлумачний словник як на
>   певну "Summa Lexicografiae"... Тaкe прагнення до повноти словника не
>   може не тішити.

Крім того в статті зазначається про проблеми, які виникли із цим словником (тут не йдеться саме про мінуси видання, а про те, що в 2010 році влада України не надто переймалася долею СУМ-20):

> Ми були прикро вражені, довідавшись від директора "Наукової думки", що
>   видавництво зібрало передплату аж на... 100 примірників Словника! Це -
>   національне приниження і ганьба! Такої ганьби ми не зазнавали навіть
>   від комуністичного тоталітаризму! Коли видавництво відмовилося
>   прийняти від нас передплату на наступний, другий Том Словника і ми
>   прямо спитали у директора видавництва: "Чи Вам влада заборонила
>   організацію передплати?!" — він промовчав, не заперечив цього,
>   пояснив, що коштів на видання 20-томовика Академія наук не виділила, а
>   тому немає жодної гарантії, що 2-й том Словника взагалі вийде.

Якщо вам цікаво, які саме зміни сталися в новому виданні, то можете прочитати ще ось цю [статтю](http://litakcent.com/2011/02/09/pershyj-iz-20-tomnoho/):

> Як показує ознайомлення з першим томом СУМ-20, його реєстр суттєво
>   розширений за рахунок лексем, стійких сполучень слів, що функціонували
>   в сучасній літературній мові, але за певних причин були не подані в
>   11-томнику (наприклад, лексика релігійної літератури; слова, що
>   вживалася до початку 1930-х років і потім були обмежені у
>   використанні; лексика, яка існувала в мові, але не була зафіксована у
>   матеріалах, що використовувалися під час створення словника в 11
>   томах). Також СУМ-20 поповнився значною мірою не лише за рахунок
>   пропущених слів, а внаслідок появи нових лексем та значень, стійких
>   словосполучень – загальновживаної лексики, як питомої, так і
>   запозиченої, словесних одиниць на позначення термінів та понять різних
>   галузей науки.

Якщо ми говоримо про СУМ-11 і його актуальність станом на 2019 рік - так, він застарів. І підтвердити це я хочу ще однією цитатою з останньої статті:

> Перевидання таких словників (***йдеться про тлумачні словники***)
>   відіграє значну суспільну роль  і, як зазначав відомий лексикограф Ф.
>   Сороколєтов,  “має неоціненне значення для історії літературної мови:
>   зміни в складі словника, в семантичній розробці та стилістичній
>   характеристиці словникового складу в словнику   свідчитимуть передусім
>   про рух і зміни самої мови, причому рух буде простежено не на окремих
>   сегментах мови, а на всій її лексико-семантичній системі”.
>
> Словниковий склад сучасної української мови (останніх десятиліть  –
>   кінця ХХ – початку ХХІ століть) характеризується входженням до нього
>   значного масиву нових слів, що відбиває процес пристосування мовної
>   системи до нових потреб комунікації у зв’язку зі стрімким розвитком
>   науки та техніки, економічними перетвореннями, виникненням нових
>   суспільних відносин, інформаційною революцією, глобалізаційними
>   процесами і т. ін. Ці процеси знайшли відображення у словотворі,
>   численних семантичних змінах різних груп лексики, освоєнні запозичених
>   слів.

Тобто бачимо, що у нашій мові з'являються нові слова, інші ж зникають, бо мова - вона розвивається так само як і наша країна. Гадаю, що з виходом останнього тому СУМ-20, СУМ-11 точно відійде у минуле (це лише моя суб'єктивна думка).